# Send HTML Email Range

Tags: vba, excel, html-email

I have the below script which sets a range to copy to an email however I require this range to go from column 1 to 13 whilst removing column 7 ("1:6","8:13") 
I have tried all sorts to correct this however each attempt results in an error.

Here is the code I'm using

```
Set RangeCopy = Sheets("Applications").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(R, 13)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
```

Any help is appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `Union` is pretty clean way of doing this. See below for a coded example given your code.

```
    Dim unionrng As Range
    Set unionrng = Application.Union(Sheets("Applications").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(r, 6)), _
                                     Sheets("Applications").Range(Cells(1, 8), Cells(r, 13)))
    Sheets("Applications").Range(unionrng.Address).SpecialCells (xlCellTypeVisible)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of options -- either by concatenating range addresses via comma or constructing separate ranges and using `Union` method. Have a look at [How to: Refer to Multiple Ranges](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb211408%28v=office.12%29.aspx) article in Microsoft Help.

Comment: Thank you, i was searching for hours trying to find this. This works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using Union in a loop like this.

```
Dim x As Long
Dim y As Long

For y = 1 To 13
    For x = 1 To r

        If y <> 7 Then
            If RangeCopy Is Nothing Then
            Set RangeCopy = cells(x, y)
            Else
            Set RangeCopy = Application.Union(RangeCopy, cells(x, y))
            End If
        End If

    Next x
Next y
```